# Disable checkbox onclick on another checkbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am new in jquery can anyone help me out for this problem.
I have 4 services in my webpage All services have one checkbox when user click any one service other three should be disable and this will be applied for others. Can anyone help me out 
Here is my Html Code with Foreach Loop.

```
<div class="one-row">
   <?php foreach ($services as $key => $allservices){ 
          if($key > 3) {  ?>
             <div class="div_img_part-2"> 
                 <span class="img_part_class-2"><img src="{{ asset('images/ServiceImages/'. $allservices['image'])}}"></span>
                     <span class="text_part_class-2">
                     <span class="check-box">
                         <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="<?php echo $allservices['id']; ?>" <?= $checked; ?> ><?php echo $allservices['name'];?>
                     </span>
                     </span>
             </div>
            <?php } }?>
       </div>
```

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: on selection of one checkbox you want to disable other three in that case why not use radio buttons instead of checkbox

Comment: I think you should just use radio button for this rather than checkbox

Comment: Yes this sloution is good. But client requirement that needs checkboxes for that

Comment: use  radio to to implement this.

Comment: Use radio buttons instead. Then put this in your CSS code: `input[type="radio"] { -webkit-appearance: checkbox; -moz-appearance: checkbox; -ms-appearance: checkbox; }` Now you see checkboxes like your client wants, but they really are just radio buttons :)

Comment: Thank you works like charm :) icecube

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others that it is best to use radio buttons for this one, but if you really insist in using checkboxes with the aid of jquery check this demo:

```js
$('.check-box :checkbox').on('change', function(){
 $('.check-box :checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one-row">
             <div class="div_img_part-2"> 
                 <span class="img_part_class-2"><img src=""></span>
                     <span class="text_part_class-2">
                     <span class="check-box">
                         <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="123">sample 1
                     </span>
                     </span>
             </div>
             <div class="div_img_part-2"> 
                 <span class="img_part_class-2"><img src=""></span>
                     <span class="text_part_class-2">
                     <span class="check-box">
                         <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="123">sample 2
                     </span>
                     </span>
             </div>
             <div class="div_img_part-2"> 
                 <span class="img_part_class-2"><img src=""></span>
                     <span class="text_part_class-2">
                     <span class="check-box">
                         <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="123"> sample 3
                     </span>
                     </span>
             </div>
       </div>
```

or just use radio buttons with the aid of css to make them appear like checkboxes

see css's [appearance](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_appearance.asp) property

Comment: oh bear in mind that IE 8 & 11 and Opera (all ver) browsers does not support the appearance property yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to disable the other checkboxes from getting selected, please follow this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.check-box :checkbox').on('change', function(){
  $('.check-box :checkbox').prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).prop('disabled', false);
})</script>
```